# What is the hydrodynamic interaction (Oseen kernel)?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fourier-transform, drag, biophysics

I am reading through the paper "[Dynamics of Membranes Driven by Actin Polymerization](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1367052/)" by Nir S. Gov and Ajay Gopinathan. In this paper, the authors develop a PDE model to explore the interplay between the dynamics of proteins that activate actin polymerization, the protrusive forces exerted on the plasma membrane by that actin polymerization, and the resulting membrane dynamics.

The model consists of two PDEs describing the density of activating proteins,  $n(r,t)$, as well as "the coordinate that measures the normal displacement of the membrane from a flat reference plane", $h(r,t)$. The equation for $\partial h/\partial t$ is described as

> The membrane deviation from flatness obeys the following equation of motion
>
> $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}=-\int\text dr'\Lambda(r-r')\kappa\nabla^4h(r')+An$$
> for a free, flat membrane. Here the first term is simply the response of a membrane that is surrounded by a fluid, **characterized by the hydrodynamic interaction kernel $\Lambda$**. After Fourier transforming into $q$-space, the hydrodynamic interaction kernel is given by $\Lambda(q)=1/4\eta q$, and the response of the free membrane is $\omega_q=\kappa q^3/4\eta$, where $\eta$ is the viscosity of the surrounding fluid.

A few sentences later in the paper they call the hydrodynamic interaction kernel an "Oseen kernel".

Searching around for "Oseen kernel" results in various results that seem adjacently related, but I can't seem to relate what I am finding to what is in the paper. What is the hydrodynamic interaction (Oseen kernel), and what is its relevance/role here?

Comment: There is also some mathematical details in this paper I have some questions on. If anyone wants to take a look at that as well, I made a post on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4589448/404425)

Comment: It looks like that $\Lambda$ is something related with a Green's function, since $\nabla^4 h$ usually appears in the thin membrane equation $D \nabla^4 h = f$, whose unsteady version can be written as $\partial_t h + D\nabla^4 h = f$. Let me have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first look, it looks like the dynamical equation of the membrane

$\partial_t h = - \kappa \Delta^2 h + f$,

being $f$ the forcing due to the reaction term $A n$ and the presence of the fluid, $f = A n + f_{fl}$, can be recast solving the coupled viscous flows at very low Reynolds, so that the  latter contribution can be related to the motion of the membrane (as a sort of feedback), in a neighborhood of the point $\mathbf{r}$ to get the equation

$\displaystyle \partial_t h(\mathbf{r},t) = - \kappa \Delta^2 h(\mathbf{r},t) + f_{fl}(\mathbf{r},t) + An(\mathbf{r},t) = \int_V \Lambda(\mathbf{r'}-\mathbf{r}) \kappa \Delta^2 h(\mathbf{r}',t) + An(\mathbf{r},t)$.

For very low Reynold's number, neglecting unsteady contributions, the governing equations of a incompressible flow of a viscous fluid at low $Re$ reads

$\left\{ \begin{array} \\ -\mu \nabla^2 \mathbf{u} + \nabla p = 0 \\ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = 0 \end{array}  \right.$

and considering a semi-infinite domain, bounded by the membrane only, the boundary conditions for small displacements read

$\mathbf{\hat{n}} \cdot \mathbf{u}\bigg|_{memb} = \partial_t h \bigg|_{memb}$.

and the load on the membrane results from the pressure

$f_{fl} = p\bigg|_{memb}$.

These are the kinematic and dynamic coupling conditions between the structural and the fluid problem.

If you can solve the fluid problem with Green's function method, it's likely that you get pressure and velocity field, as a function of the displacement of the membrane. I guess that here it is where the Oseen's kernel appear. After the solution is found, it could be possible to put the solution of the structural and fluid problem together.

Now, how to actually solve the problem to retrieve the desired formula could require some effort, but I think that is the right way to find that formula. I'm trying, but I'm not sure I'm finding the solution soon.

Hope this could help.

Comment: I should note that the focus of the model is not the fluid dynamics. Rather it is the dynamics of the membrane (and the activator protein distribution). But thanks for the feedback. I will have to consider it in more detail when I am able to.

Comment: I had no time yet, to work on it. If you find something good, please leave an update

Comment: Anyway, if you take the divergence of the momentum equation, you get a Laplace equation for $p$, so that Stokes equations can be recasted as a coupledsystem of a Laplace equation for $p$ and a Poisson equation for $\mathbf{u}$

Comment: Wouldn't the Fourier transform of $\Lambda$ being $1/4\eta q$ suggest that in r-space we have $\Lambda(r)=i\cdot\text{sgn}(r)/8\eta$

Comment: what is $q$? I should have asked before...

Comment: The spatial frequency in the Fourier transform

Comment: It could not be that way if the authors (or whoever originally wrote the problem) have used some assumption about the symmetry of the function to be transformed. As as example, with an assumption of the spherical symmetry of the function, Fourier transform $\mathscr{F}(\mathbf{k}) = \int_{\Omega} f(\mathbf{r}) e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}} d^3 \mathbf{r}$ could become $\int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int_{\phi=0}^{\pi} \int_{r=0}^{\infty} f(r) e^{-i k_r r} r^2 \sin \phi dr d\phi d\theta = 4 \pi  \int_{r=0}^{\infty} f(r) e^{-i k_r r} r^2 dr $

Comment: Did you manage to come up with something decent?

Comment: My project has somewhat drifted away from this topic at the moment, but if I have to return to it I will let you know!